# substring functionality when ignoring the stop

Tags: python, julia

Is there a way to use the string `length` instead of a `stop` with `SubString` instead of an error being thrown because `SubString` reached the end of the string before the `stop` was reached?

In Python it works like this:

```
string = "Hello, World"
string2 = string[5:20]
print(string2)
```

But in Julia, this throws an error:

```
string = "Hello, World"
string2 = SubString(string,5,20)
print(string2)
```

Comment: `SubString(string,5,min(length(string),20))`?

Comment: You mis-typed it (parentheses mis-balanced).

Comment: @ScottHunter I see what I did now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try also `@view string[5:min(end,20)]` which is equivalent but shorter version of Scott's suggestion.

Comment: Also, it is always wise to think about Unicode. The way `string` is setup in Julia, indices can be invalid. Thus `string[5:20]` can raise an exception on generic Unicode text, which might not be desired.

Comment: @DanGetz I'm getting this error trying to substring now `ERROR: BoundsError: attempt to access 144-codeunit String at index [0:65]` and i'm trying to figure out what would be causing it. i haven't seen codeunit mentioned in any other language

Comment: Julia has 1-based indexing of arrays and strings, this means, the first character/element of a string/vector is `s[1]` and not `s[0]`. So I think you should try to index using [1:66] instead of [0:65]. As for codeunit, it is a term from the Unicode standard which is approximately equivalent to a Unicode character. Unicode isn't straightforward and a little digging and learning is necessary to manage strings in the currently mostly Unicode world. Fortunately, there are many excellent resources on the internet in any media form.

Comment: R and Julia are the only ones, if I'm wrong, that start at 1 for indexing. I'll have to do some editing and try again.